# How to hook inside the AlarmClock system of android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm creating an android app, we want to add a feature that play something after each the user has canceled an alarm.
I doubt that this is possible but asking anyway, because otherwise i'll need to create yet another alarm app and bundle it inside the main app.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Would [this](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/02/android-basics-alarm-service/) post have anything to do with what you want to do? Talks about creating pending intents for when an alarm sounds.

Comment: This is not related, it talks about how to register for something to happen on a given time. It is like a way to get notified at a given future time.

Answer (score 0):

The [Alarm Clock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html) class helps you build an intent to set a system alarm. It's new in API 9. More features and access to the timer function was added in API 19.

It's still pretty limited. Once you create an alarm or timer, you can't change it or cancel it.